# How to get date / time of error into HHVM error log

Tags: nginx, php, hhvm, hiphop

I'm running HHVM 3.1.0 and nginx.  I'm set to send errors in HHVM to it's own log file, not return them through nginx.  One thing I noticed is the errors lack any type of timestamp or date /time listed, just the string of the error, here's some examples:

```
\nWarning: Invalid argument: function: not a valid callback array in /srv/http/nx/app/model/Session.php on line 57
\nFatal error: Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) in /srv/http/nx/app/model/Session.php on line 57 
\nWarning: Invalid argument: function: not a valid callback array
```

Is there a way to better format these error log entries to be more usable?  At a minimum to have the date and time show up?   Is there a way to pass errors back through `nginx` to log them in the way that `php-fpm` would?  Here's an example of using php-fpm and getting errors in my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (notice the nice format):

```
  [04-Aug-2014 13:53:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/http/nx/app/controller/website/SEOFinds.php on line 164
```

For reference, here's my HHVM config file in `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid
date.timezone="America/New_York"
; hhvm specific

hhvm.server.file_socket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
;hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false

hhvm.eval.jit_warmup_requests = 0
```

Below is my nginx location block:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
                 fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                 fastcgi_buffers 128 16k;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index   index.php;
                 fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include         fastcgi_params;
         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time stamp is controlled by the `hhvm.log.header` INI setting. If you set it to `true` you'll get time stamps in your logs.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you know how to get them passed into the nginx error logs?